# Tmux for Vim-R-plugin?

Tags: r, vim

When I open my .Rprofile there's showing this message:

```
".Rprofile" 63L, 2237C
Please, install the 'Tmux' application to enable the Vim-R-plugin.
[Press <Enter> to continue]
```

But when I tried to install Tmux,

```
d-128-109-40:~ dz2t$ brew install Tmux
Warning: tmux-1.8 already installed
```

Does anybody know what's the reason?

Comment: Sounds like a path problem. Can you open Tmux from the command line? And what happens when you run `system(tmux)` form within R?

Comment: It may be [solved here](https://github.com/jalvesaq/screenR/issues/1)

Answer (score 0):

Is your .vimrc configured to have tmux and vim-r working together?
You can follow the instructions below and use the provided .vimrc and .tmux.conf:

http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r